# Download File with Notification

Tags: android

I've been trying to complete this for the past week, but i can't seem to get it to work!

I have successfully created a notification that has a `ProgressBar`, and i have it incrementing across (in a seperate thread) with `Sleep(1000);` I also have a method `downloadFile(String url)` which successfully downloads a file in a separate thread (with no UI), but i can't seem to be able to integrate them at all!

Any help would be appreciated, Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for it.

Examples are on the link itself

Comment: Thanks, that seems helpful! I'm not too sure how the Async functionality would help me here with downloading a single file? By the looks of that class it's for multiple downloads at once?

Comment: when you are downloading somethings, it will help u in downloaded in a non UI thread and updating the UI from right there